# Is possible determine value of column using a query to another table with stored procedures?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2

I'm working in a project where I need to make changes in the database to create a history of managers and status of projects and use it, instead of the already existing columns of managers and status in a projects table. The problem is: there are several aplications that may or may not be using those fields in this old table and would be almost impossible find all the aplications that use those fields to make them use the new tables.

So, I had been thinking, there is any way to create a stored procedure in a db2 database that can make the values in the manager and status columns in the projects table come from a query to the new history tables?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I think what you want is called a view.

Comment: I don't know if a view could do what i need because, since I'm implementing a history tables, there will be several entries in the manager tables for the same project, so I would need to get the manager with bigger timestamp in the history table that worked in that project. A view can do that?

Comment: If you can write a `SELECT` statement "to get the manager with bigger timestamp", you can create a view that would do the saem.

Comment: I will study a little more about views and try this aproach. Thank you.